# Is it bad to answer "Don't do this, it is bad Android design"?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Example question:
[Splash Screen in Android using Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885480/splash-screen-in-android-using-fragment/23885908#23885908)

I am a big fan of Android design, and I design all of my apps perfectly according to the Android design guidelines. The guidelines are that Android apps should not have splash screens and this guy is asking how to implement a splash screen. So I answered he should not do it.

I want to discourage people to ignore the guidelines. Is it bad to answer like this?

Comment: Look at it this way: The project owner has decided they _want_ a splash screen. The developer is only responsible for implementing what they are told, not necessarily the design - in these circumstances is the answer useful? Does it _answer_ the question? I'm not saying that's the OP's situation (actually [it does sound like it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885480/splash-screen-in-android-using-fragment/23885908#comment36771876_23885908)) - this is a (sadly) typical scenario for why some devs ask to do things they "shouldn't".

Comment: I'd post that as a comment. It doesn't answer the question "How do I implement this", thus it should not be posted as an answer.

Comment: Educating others about best practices around design/coding is a very good approach. Regarding your specific answer, I would have mentioned all that as a comment because in its current form it is not an answer (it maybe considered an attempt to answer at best).

Comment: @AD7six - part of the role and responsibility of a developer is to tell designers and users when they are wrong and we should provide them with the reasons to win their arguments.

Comment: @Mark I've had _plenty_ of "that's a bad idea" discussions IRL, and written plenty of "you really shouldn't be doing that" answers; I think there's a big difference between e.g. "do not store passwords in plain text" and "no, you really shouldn't put a splash screen on your app". To me it's all about emphasis, if I write an answer of that type it's not "Don't do that" but rather "You really shouldn't do that, these are the reasons why but if you _really_ need what you've asked for this is how to do it." typically with only the last 1/4 of the answer answering the question as asked.

Comment: And generally speaking, if the person paying the bills is adamant that they want <that's not a good idea> - the developer is not in a position to do anything about it except do it or walk away. It's unrealistic to assume developers (of all levels of experience - in this example the person asking sounds quite inexperienced) have the ability to change the mind of the design decision maker.

Comment: [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891/165773)

Comment: I am still trying to get past "I design all of my apps perfectly..."

Comment: I've actually had _abuse_ from people, here, for asking complicated Android questions. There is nothing quite as infuriating as having external requirements that I have no control over force me to do something which I know is a bad idea, and then have people insult me for those external requirements. It's arrogant, alienating and desperately unhelpful. Answers that say 'this is a really bad idea because X but if you absolutely have to then...' are fine, and have written lots myself, but it's important to remember: if you're not actually answering their question, it's probably not worth saying.

Comment: I guess they should redesign the Stack Exchange app... oops! ;)

Comment: Paradoxically, if you *ask* for what the best practice is, your question often gets closed. But if you ask how to do you something which is not best practice, you get the advice for free.

Comment: Tell the OP not to do it:  [get 4500 upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @SamIam worse, that's a matter of tell the OP not to do something similar to what they asked about, but not actually what they asked, get 4500 upvotes.

Comment: @SamIam It's all about the style points ☺

Comment: I agree with others who say you didn't actually answer the question. If, however, the OP is trying to do something which might cause actual problems in stability, functionality, security etc then offer a valid alternative. As for splash screens...I just add a comment and a link to "Splash screens are evil, don't use them" http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Comment: @jdm The first rule of best practice is that you do not talk about best practice.

Comment: @DavidGiven You always have control over requirements; you are the programmer, if you do not implement them, they do not get implemented.

Comment: @Alice I like my job. I want to keep it.

Comment: Guidelines are guidelines, not rules, and are sometimes wrong or irrelevant to a specific situation. By all means call attention to the guideline, but you are not the Android police. If you have your own reasons why splash screens are bad, or whatever, give them. Just try to do so in a way that's pertinent to the OP's case. Today's best practice is tomorrow's "Can you believe they used to do that?!".

Comment: @DavidGiven Which means you make a choice. Which is, again, control.

Answer (score 96):

If what the OP asked for is possible, then it is insufficient for an answer to only say not to do it.  It doesn't matter how bad whatever the OP is trying to accomplish is.  If you're answering a question, you need to *answer the question* - even if that means enabling someone to do things the wrong way.

An ideal answer in this case would give the OP exactly what he/she is looking for, but with a giant warning at the top.  Something like this:

> **Warning:** Before you follow this advice, you need to understand why X is bad. [Explain why or link to relevant resources.]  If you understand the risks and are still sure that you need X anyway, keep reading.  Otherwise, just use Y instead.

If you're unwilling to put together that kind of answer, you can still be helpful by leaving a comment on the question that points the OP (and anyone else who found the question) to the better way of doing things.

Comment: I really like this approach. It bugs me to no end to just get a "don't do that" answer. Often, I know I shouldn't do it a certain way, but have a compelling reason. At the end of the day, "don't do that" isn't an answer to "how can I do this"? I wish you'd answer more of my questions! ;-)

Comment: Completely agree - sometimes I do lots of things that smell, but only when the requirements demand it. If I ask a question about the smelly task then I'm not really interested in being told not to do it, I'm probably aware of that already. Similarly I when answering those questions, I'll answer them and maybe add a suggestion of a better way, in case the asker isn't aware

Comment: Disagree strongly; the [concept of mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#.22Unasking.22_the_question) is a very important one. Often the question needs to be unasked.

Comment: @Alice _Who_ needs it to be unasked, though? Are you sure you're not succumbing to your own need to demonstrate your knowledge? The only thing you know about them is that they've asked the question; you don't know anything about the context in which they've asked it. Assuming that you know _so much more_ about the subject than them that you can simply disregard everything they've said because you know better is simply arrogance. Sure, tell them it's a bad idea. But answer the question at the same time. Because if they didn't need an answer, they wouldn't have asked it.

Comment: @DavidGiven That's empirically untrue; people ask questions to which they do not need an answer to, sometimes overtly (philosophical questions), and sometimes unknowingly (asking a question that does not actually fulfil their needs). An example is if someone asks how to slice 3 letters off a string, when what they really need is to know how to find a file extension. The question they asked is not a solution to their real problem; they are too far down the "decision tree" if you will. Many questions I've had to answer in the past are this sort of non-question. Unasking it is the right call.

Comment: @ALice In other words, you're deliberately ignoring what they asked in favour of what _you_ think they should have asked. That really is arrogance. Remember, you are here for their benefit. Be humble. If you think they're making a context error, then _ask them_. 'Here is how to remove the last three letters from a string... but are actually trying to extract the file extension? If so, consider using Path.extractFileExtension() because extensions might not be three letters.' Otherwise you're not helping, and worse, you're being rude.

Comment: Incidentally, apologies if I'm coming on a bit strong here, but I've seen this plenty of times and it drives me absolutely nuts. Answers like this always seem to end up sounding like "Hi! I'm going to expend a significant amount of time carefully not answering your question, in a thoroughly patronising manner, because I don't have enough respect for you to believe that your question might actually be asking about the thing you need to know!" I think it would actually be _less_ rude just to swear at them. So... going off to breathe into a paper bag now.

Answer (score 26):

> Is it bad to answer?

Yes, there's a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android). Vote to close.

> Is it bad to answer like this?

Yes, place a comment. Unless the answer is "You **can't**", your answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Why the heck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen-in-android is closed though? It's definitely not asking for a tool, as the close reason suggests.

Comment: Closing three year old questions is silly, and that reason indeed doesn't make sense at all. Reopening won't change anything though.

Comment: @CodeCaster Closing old question is fine and helps stop the "But *that* question is still open" arguments when newer questions are closed. Of course, this assumes the closure reason is valid.

Comment: @Athari The question should be closed, IMO, as "too broad" under the current categories. I agree that the original closure reason is quite wrong.

Answer (score 9):

There's a difference between "someone's opinion is that it should not be done" and "what you're trying to do is not possible". If your answer is the first of these, as you describe, then it should not be an answer (but as a statement augmenting something that does answer the question, it's fine). It should instead be a comment or just ignored completely.

Comment: It's not "someone's opinion", it's official guidelines.

Comment: @Agent_L guidelines are still someone else's opinion. A comment that explains it's against guidelines is certainly fine, but that's not an answer.

Answer (score 8):

I think it depends on how "bad" the task is that OP wants to do.

For example, on [How to force https for only the pages need to be authorized in a Asp.Net MVC 5 site?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23726273/247702) I answered that OP shouldn't do it and explained the security risk of doing it.

The example you give is less "bad", adding a splash screen doesn't add any risk to the application. When finding such a question with a search engine, seeing "don't do this" can be frustrating.

I'm having a bit of trouble expressing myself but I hope you get what I mean with these examples.

Answer (score 4):

What I will sometimes do is start of by saying that this is not recommended practice, and let the OP know why.

But then to follow up with how to do it anyway.

There are some users here who will insist that certain Android techniques are impossible, and not answer the question, even though there may be workarounds if you try to put yourself in the OP's situation. I find this very distracting.

Sometimes we have to understand that clients can insist on certain designs / features that Android developers don't like. My favourites always start like this "The iOS version has...."

Answer (score 1):

It is not answering the question, so I don't think you should post it as an answer, but instead use the comments.

I'm encountering situations like this sometimes as well in the JavaScript world where people are using the global namespace for nearly everything. When I encounter it, I usually provide two solutions:
* One that solves the question like the OP wants
* One that solves the question how it could be resolved (even better)

If I don't want to put that much time/effort in it, I usually add a section in my answer with points to remind/consider when using this approach, in my situation (the global namespace), I would probably link to an answer where it's explained why using it would be bad + outlining how he could improve it.

---

In your situation I would probably have placed a comment like this:

> Why do you want a splash screen? It's considered bad design because users don't like to wait.

(or something similar)

Then the OP would have responded in the way he did, by leaving a comment stating that the client wants it that way (which sounds like a valid reason as well, if it's technically solvable). By using the comments you would not have "polluted" the answer section of the question, keeping this site "clean".

Answer (score -5):

It's OK to answer like this. Explanation and link to official guidelines should follow.

Devs, and especially mobile devs, are constantly struggling with clients who refuse to acknowledge that it's more important for CompanyX app for Android to be consistent with Android and NOT with CompanyX app for iOS. By posting good "why not" answers you provide devs with arguments to back up "this design is wrong" case.

Comment: Why do I have to follow someone else guidelines, even if they're so-called **official**? If I think something is right the way I want to do it then either answer with an *actual* answer, comment with your views, or just don't interact. Doing otherwise means showing arrogance and prone to time waste for the asker.

Comment: @AlperTuran When you're programming for certain platform, users expect certain behaviors. It doesn't matter at all what **you** think is right, guidelines explain what **users** think is right. You're not writing for yourself.