# Questions on corner-cases, obscure usage - get downvoted immediately

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes

I've been on SE for a while and while and mainly use it for C & Python programming questions.

As you could imagine, *nearly* all of the obvious questions have already been asked. So I find when it comes to asking a question, its almost always ends up being a corner-case, obscure-situation... (where existing conventional wisdom doesn't *necessarily* apply, or the specific case is an exception to the rule).

Apart from stating in the question that I know I'm asking about some corner case (which I do at times), Im not sure how else to ask these questions.

My concern is:

- Just because a question is about a corner case, doesn't mean its an invalid question.
  *(though understandably, it may not get up-voted much since not many other developers would run into the problem)*.
- Such questions are often swiftly replied and/or down-voted with a *"Why would anyone want to do that!"*.
- Knee-jerk reactions to such questions are a deterrent to asking questions on rare problems.

Maybe I have to put some big disclaimer above the questions saying:

> **yes this is bad practice in almost-all-cases and mostly you would avoid doing ... but one time I needed to because ... and there are a few cases where the typical solutions fail.**

Does anyone have advice on asking questions in a field where most common-cases have already been covered.

---

*Am willing to accept some of my questions are down-voted because they are straight out bad too :)*

Comment: If you're referring to your latest question, I only see one downvote.

Comment: If you're knowingly using bad practices for one reason or another, then it might be a good idea to add a disclaimer like that. It doesn't need an indepth explanation, but a short statement explaining that you know why it's bad, and why you're doing it that way, certainly couldn't hurt.

Comment: @Jeremiah Winsley, yep, makes sense, even though a ask such questions with real caution now, will try be even more careful in future... _also cursious as to why *this* questions is downvoted_ - if it doesn't follow some SE guidelines, thats fine, I don't mind to delete it, but would be good to know why.

Comment: This is Meta, there's no rep involved. Downvotes just mean someone disagrees with the premise of the post, not that it's a bad question.

Comment: Pretty much all of your questions have a positive vote total, so I don't quite see the pattern here. And the most recent one has one single downvote, which is very little data. I actually think it's better than a large portion of questions being posted on SO. I would probably upvote it, were in not for my personal policy of not voting on posts discussed on meta (I refuse to feed the Meta Effect).

Comment: It's a problem with stack overflow voting system...

Comment: `"Such questions are often swiftly replied and/or down-voted with a "Why would anyone want to do that!"`. So, it's not only my impression

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that your corner case isn't an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), more often than not if you're doing something that is way off the beaten path you're probably falling into that category.

Next if you're really sure it isn't an XY problem, be sure to clearly explain what you're doing and why you're doing it. Don't get upset when people ask "Why would anyone want to do that?" if you haven't been clear about why you would want to do it.

Lastly be open to other approaches. Whether its an XY problem or not your out of the box, corner case method may not be the best way to address the issue.

Sometimes the answer to "How do I foo the bar?" is:
"NO! Don't ever foo the bar, unicorns will cry and the sun will explode..."
or
"You shouldn't foo the bar, use baz instead..."

Comment: Generally a helpful answer (thanks :) ). But explaining why *exactly*, can draw attention to unimportant details - and conflate issues. For example I might mention using one technology, and in reply I get recommended to switch to an alternative. Even if this is a reasonable suggestion (in general), its really not the point of the question.

Answer (score -2):

I find such corner-case questions very interesting, thus for me it is some kind of paradox that many of such questions get downvoted. Disclaimer is not a bad idea. In addition I propose you tag such questions with [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hacking) tag.

Comment: This seems more a comment then an answer

Comment: @ideasman42 well, you asked for advice, so that's my advice. Does answer need to be lengthy?

Comment: (note, I didn't down-vote the post) & the first part of the answer reads more like a comment. I didn't know about the `hacking` tag. thanks.