# Should accepted answers that fall below 0 have their accepted status rescinded?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

Maybe I don't fully understand what accepted answers are for.  Sure they result in reputation for the answerer, but aren't they also meant to be a means of focusing the attention of future visitors on a useful answer?

If so, aren't accepted answers with a score of less than zero actually harmful to those future visitors?  Would it be useful to rescind the accepted status (with or without rescinding the answerer's reputation) in [such a case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9572734/34806) so as to not unnecessarily draw future visitors' attention to it?

Comment: There are lots of related questions. For example, I once upon a time asked to [Deemphasise the accept mark if there's an answer the community strongly prefers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253752/deemphasise-the-accept-mark-if-theres-an-answer-the-community-strongly-prefers). Maybe read some of that. Or maybe something more pointed at the reason for accepted answers: [Do accepted answers still serve a useful purpose?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214291/do-accepted-answers-still-serve-a-useful-purpose).

Comment: Only the OP decides whether an answer is accepted or not, so no.

Comment: _"...but aren't they also meant to be a means of focusing the attention of future visitors on a useful answer?"_ Nope. Accepted answers are only meant to show the answer that _helped the OP the most_ or that the OP found to be the best. The OP doesn't necessarily know best, and if they find out they're wrong, they may not bother to come back and change it. Honestly, my first time here, I noticed an answer with a little green check, but it was greyed out and had a negative number next to it. This made me stop and look at the answer below it which had a decent positive number. Just for example.

Comment: Also related: [Why are negative score accepted answers still at the top?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255706/why-are-negative-score-accepted-answers-still-at-the-top)

Comment: Removing the acceptance would be highly inappropriate.  The OP has the right to indicate what answer they think is best.  Pinning that answer to the top, even if the community strongly disagrees as to the best solution, is another matter entirely.

Comment: There are situations where the accepted answer has a low score but not because it's wrong. Example: Asker asks how to do something that's a bad idea. Someone answers with how to do the bad idea. Community down-votes it because it's a bad idea but Asker accepts the answer because they've been told they have to do the bad idea: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256314/is-it-bad-to-answer-dont-do-this-it-is-bad-android-design

Comment: @GeorgeJempty, We need more insulation from pile-on vote-down effects, not less.  I think the choosing of an accepted answer should remain squarely in the OP's court.

Answer (score 4):

Well, to answer this, lets look at some basic questions

**What is an accepted answer?**

An accepted answer is supposed to be the answer which the OP found useful. It does not matter what kind of answer it is. If the OP feels this is the answer that helped him, then it is his choice to accept it, whether is answer is good or bad.

**Is an accepted answer the best answer?**

Not always. The community will up-vote the good answer, so the best answer would be the answer with the highest score, there is no need for the accepted answer to be considered the best answer.

So, regarding *"but aren't they also meant to be a means of focusing the attention of future visitors on a useful answer?"*

The accepted answer is not the answer that Future users should look at. It is pretty clear that one should look at the highest voted answer, not the accepted answer. That Fact will not change even in the Future ( unless the moderators decide to change the very meaning of an accepted answer ).

So, regarding *"Should accepted answers that fall below 0 have their accepted status rescinded?"*

No, only the OP should be allowed to do that. There are many answers that are tailor made for a particular problem the OP may be facing, and they might get accepted even if there are other better answers. But, that just means the OP found this answer the most useful, the answer having down-votes does not remove the validity of that answer.

Also, **consider the case when an answer got down-voted, but was later edited and got accepted, but the down-votes were not removed**, having that answer unaccepted by us would just be cruel.

If the answer is clearly wrong, down-vote it and leave a comment saying it is wrong. Let the others decide about it then.

So in all, I feel that the accepted answer should be chosen by the OP and only he should have the ability to un-accept them.

Comment: _"If the answer is clearly wrong, then you can flag it..."_ The other two options you list here, downvoting and commenting, are 100% correct. But flags are _not_ to be used on wrong answers. The mods cannot judge an answer based on technical merit. If you flag an answer for being wrong/incorrect, your flag will be declined.

Comment: @Kendra, will take that into consideration. Thanks for notifying.